# Flutter run ProcessException on xcodebuild

Tags: flutter

I am trying to launch map projects from https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter, but getting the same error. I have already made on iOS build on this PC.

> flutter run
>
> ### exception
>
> ProcessException: ProcessException: No such file or directory
>   Command: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project
>   /Users/mikelampi/Downloads/amap_base_flutter-master/location/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
>   -target Runner -showBuildSettings

```
#0      _ProcessImpl._runAndWait (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:489:7)
#1      _runNonInteractiveProcessSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:634:18)
#2      Process.runSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:66:12)
#3      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:83:20)
#4      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:343:48)
#5      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:297:10)
#6      XcodeProjectInterpreter.getBuildSettings (package:flutter_tools/src/ios/xcodeproj.dart:177:24)
#7      IosProject.buildSettings (package:flutter_tools/src/project.dart:364:42)
#8      IosProject.isSwift (package:flutter_tools/src/project.dart:356:23)
#9      RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:229:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand._sendUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:411:58)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:392:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#17     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
#19     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#24     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#25     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#26     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#29     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#30     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#31     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#32     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#34     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#35     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#36     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#37     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#38     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#40     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#41     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#42     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#43     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#44     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#45     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#46     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#47     main (file:///Users/mikelampi/Progs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#48     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#49     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. In my own codebase there is no attempt to load iOS (which I am not targeting) but I get this error trying out the google example code

Comment: Did you solve it? =)